# how to store values in Mongodb using mongoose in MeanStack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

i am using angularjs db ismongodb with the help of mongoose .i create a simple entry form in mongoose schema but it's shows an  **$http.post(...).success is not a function** i don't know how to solve this anyone help how to solve this problem i am new in this technology

## Html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Controller/MongooseCrud.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

    <div ng-controller="MongooseController">



        <label for="email">Email: </label>
      <input type="email" name="email"  ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    <label for="age">Age: </label>
      <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="user.age"/><br />
      <input type="Button"  value="submit" ng-click="AddNewDetails()">

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

## Controller

```
var app = angular.module("App", [ ]);


app.controller('MongooseController', ['$scope', '$http' ,'$window', '$filter',


function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter) {



    $scope.AddNewDetails = function ( ) {

        $http.post('/AddNewDetails',  $scope.user).success(function (response) {


            console.log((response));
        }).error(function (err) {

        });
    };


}]);
```

## Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/crud');

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);

app.post('/AddNewDetails', function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    new user({
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age


    }).save(function (err, doc) {

        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(doc);
            res.send('Successfully inserted!');
        }
    });
});




app.listen(8082);
console.log("server running on port 8082");
```

Comment: you have not defined `email` in the schema

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect format.

$http service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

works as such
    $http.get('url').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: i change the syntax now error is gone but values are not stored in DB

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me what error you are getting on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use service... In that you have to change the word post into create. It Will gives you the best result.

```html
angular.module('yourApp').factory("yourService", function($http){

 return{
  create : function(insertData){
           return $http.post("http://localhost:yourHost/AddNewDetails/", insertData);
       }
});
```